# Attached DB is not accessible to make connection

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I created a DB using following code.

```
Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Server=.\SQLExpress;Data Source=;Integrated Security=SSPI")
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("", conn)

cmd.CommandText = "CREATE DATABASE MyDBTest22 ON ( FILENAME = 'D:\dbTestATTTTTTT.mdf' ), ( FILENAME = 'D:\dbTestATTTTTTT_log.ldf' ) FOR ATTACH"

conn.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cmd.Dispose()
conn.Dispose()
```

It ran without any error but when I opened SSMS, I could not see my file attached to the server. Also, I tried to make a connection, but it says file does not exist but when I tried to re-run the above code, it says File already exists.

Something wrong with my way of doing it? I want to see it attached with the instance of my SQL Server Express 2005, using SSMS.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a database to connect to in your connection string - if you want to attach a file, I would recommend connecting to the `master` database:

```
Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=master;Integrated Security=SSPI")
```

Comment: Now the error changed: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: I have made sure the SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections and also exception has been made in Firewall

Comment: @FurqanSehgal: try my new connection string - you had both `Server=.\SQLExpress` in there, as well as an empty `Data Source=` and that `Data Source=` also denotes the server, really - I didn't see that. You need to use `server=.\sqlexpress` and then `database=master` instead

Comment: Thanks.  Now the error is Unable to open the physical file "D:\dbTestATTTTTTT.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(error not found)".

Comment: @FurqanSehgal: well - the error is pretty clear - is that file there?? If you want to attach a database file on a given remote machine, that `.MDF` file must be **on that machine's** D: drive - not your local computer's D: drive...

Comment: But I am trying to attach it on my own computer's SQL Server instance?

Comment: So is that file available on your `D:\` drive??

Comment: yes, I experimented with a new file.  It has got attached.  Then I detached it and ran the same code again, it gives error.  But new files are getting attached.  What is this?

Comment: @FurqanSehgal: it seems that the file is still under SQL Server's control after detaching .... strange ..... I don't know why that would be the case, sorry ....